# Python - Apace Beam [GCP] - PubSub to GCS working with direct runner, but not with DataFlow runner

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

I have an Apache beam pipeline written in python which reads data from pubSub Topic, then aggregates and transposes the data and writes to GCS.

When I run the python script using direct runner, the pipeline works and GCS file is populated. When I try to deploy in cloud dataflow it throws me an error :

[image: Error Message for Dataflow runner]

Error log in Dataflow UI :

[image: Dataflow logs]

I tried the same transformation to write back to BigQuery Table and it worked fine with dataflow runner.

Apache Beam Version : apache-beam==2.27.0

Command used to execute :

```
python3 pubSubToGCS.py --runner DataFlow --project <PROJECT_ID> \
--temp_location gs://<PROJECT_ID>-temp-bucket/tmp \
--staging_location gs://<PROJECT_ID>-temp-bucket/staging \
--streaming --job_name dataloading --region us-central1 \
--SUBSCRIPTION_NAME projects/<PROJECT_ID>/subscriptions/RawSensorReadings-sub \
--GCS_PATH gs://<PROJECT_ID>/RawDataReadings/TEST
```

pubSubToGCS.py :

```
import argparse
import datetime
import logging
import time
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
import apache_beam.transforms.window as window
import pandas as pd
from apache_beam.io import WriteToText

def convertToCsv(sensorValues):
  (timestamp, values) =  sensorValues
  df = pd.DataFrame(values)
  df.columns = ["Sensor","Value"]
  csvStr =  str(timestamp)+","+",".join(str(x) for x in list(df.groupby(["Sensor"]).mean().T.iloc[0]))
  return csvStr

def roundTime(dt=None, roundTo=60):
   if dt == None : dt = datetime.datetime.now()
   seconds = (dt.replace(tzinfo=None) - dt.min).seconds
   rounding = (seconds+roundTo/2) // roundTo * roundTo
   return str(dt + datetime.timedelta(0,rounding-seconds,-dt.microsecond))

def run(subscription_path, output_gcs_path, interval=1, pipeline_args=None):

    with beam.Pipeline(options=PipelineOptions( pipeline_args, streaming=True, save_main_session=True)) as p:
      data = (p
        | 'ReadData' >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(subscription=subscription_path)
        | "Decode" >> beam.Map(lambda x: x.decode('utf-8'))
        #RAW messages comes in format :

        # ....
        # 2021-02-15 11:58:25.637077,Pressure_2,2064.6582700689737
        # 2021-02-15 11:58:25.638462,Pressure_3,2344.5496650659934
        # 2021-02-15 11:58:25.639584,Pressure_4,2124.8628543586183
        # 2021-02-15 11:58:25.640560,Pressure_5,2026.8313489428847
        # ....      
        | "Convert to list" >> beam.Map(lambda x: x.split(","))
        | "to tuple" >> beam.Map(lambda x: (roundTime(datetime.datetime.strptime(x[0],'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'), roundTo = interval), [x[1] , float(x[2]) ] ))
        # After converting to tuple : 
        # ('2021-02-15 11:58:23', ['Pressure_4', 2053.5058784228463])
        # ('2021-02-15 11:58:23', ['Pressure_5', 1554.4377708096179])
        # ('2021-02-15 11:58:23', ['Pressure_5', 1584.4305417337491])
        # ('2021-02-15 11:58:24', ['Pressure_1', 2392.3361259850535])
        # ('2021-02-15 11:58:24', ['Pressure_2', 1975.1719957768883])
        # ('2021-02-15 11:58:24', ['Pressure_3', 2713.306279034812])
        # ('2021-02-15 11:58:24', ['Pressure_4', 1902.3089540631288])
        # ('2021-02-15 11:58:24', ['Pressure_5', 1932.9791896923427])
        # ('2021-02-15 11:58:26', ['Pressure_1', 2022.983225929031])
        # ('2021-02-15 11:58:26', ['Pressure_2', 1799.7312618480091])
        # ('2021-02-15 11:58:26', ['Pressure_3', 2166.0263912901733])

        | "Window" >> beam.WindowInto(window.FixedWindows(15))
        | "Groupby" >> beam.GroupByKey()
        | "convert to csv" >> beam.Map(convertToCsv)
        # After aggegation and Transpose : (Header just for reference, not included in PCOLL)
        # Timestamp          , Pressure_1      , Pressure_2      , Pressure_3       , Pressure_4       , Pressure_5
        # 2021-02-15 12:09:35,1965.012352391227,2004.429036333092,2251.4681479138094,1771.5563402502842,1756.392145648632
        # 2021-02-15 12:09:36,1825.3075719663318,2259.6443056432713,2072.838378531564,2120.7269395022995,1783.3072412809652
        # 2021-02-15 12:09:37,2275.9356184022963,1989.6216653552221,2157.401713549938,1657.4214496485536,1923.4706666235156
        # 2021-02-15 12:09:38,1892.8002062318985,1945.9966592074343,2317.891325891871,1636.2570086301153,1971.247401688967
        # 2021-02-15 12:09:39,1944.2184082592953,1913.9882349839,2244.7614223797464,1893.985945158099,1579.50215334007
        | "Write to GCS" >> WriteToText(output_gcs_path)
        # This works with Direct runner, but with dataflow runner doesn't work
      )

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument(
        "--SUBSCRIPTION_NAME",
        help="The Cloud Pub/Sub subscription to read from.\n"
        '"projects/<PROJECT_ID>/subscriptions/<SUBSCRIPTION_NAME>".',
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        "--GCS_PATH",
        help = "Path to GCP cloud storage buket\n"
        '"<gs://<PROJECT_ID>/<BUCKET>/<PATH>"')
    parser.add_argument(
        "--AGGREGATION_INTERVAL",
        type = int,
        default = 1,
        help="Number of seconds to aggregate.\n",

    )
    args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args()
    run(
        args.SUBSCRIPTION_NAME,
        args.GCS_PATH,
        args.AGGREGATION_INTERVAL,
        pipeline_args
      )
```

Comment: Is there a more detailed error in the dataflow console (web UI)?

Comment: @robertwb I couldn't find a detailed log in the dataflow console, attaching the log screenshot.